# Best approach to create a tag cloud from input text

Tags: php, mysql, text, input, tag-cloud

I was wondering what would be the best approach to generate a tag cloud from a input text (while user is typing it). For example, if user types a story's text containing keywords "sci-fi, technology, effects", the tag cloud will be formed from each of this keywords ordered by relevance according to their frequency on every story. The tag cloud will be displayed in descending order and using the same font size, it's not the display algorithm, but the search algorithm I should implement. 
I'm using mysql and php. 
Should I stick to MATCH...AGAINST clause? should I implement a tags table?

**More details**
I have a mysql table containing a lot of stories. When user is typing one of his/her own, I want to display a tag cloud containing the most frequent words, taken from the input text, occurring on this set of stories that are saved on my db.
The tag cloud will only be used to show to the user the relevance of the words he/she has entered on his/her own story according to the frequency they occur on all stories entered by all users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you need to do is more clearly define the purpose of your tagging system.  Do you want to simply build tags based on the words that occur most frequently within the text?  This strikes me as something designed with search rankings in mind.

...Or do you want your content to be better organized, and the tag cloud be a way of providing a better user experience and creating more distinct relationships between pieces of content (ie both of these are tagged sci-fi, so display them in the sci-fi category).

If the former is the case, you might not need to do anything but:

- Explode the text by a delimiter like a single space `explode(' ', $content);`
- Have a list (possibly in a config file or within the script itself) of words which will occur frequently which you want to exclude from being tags (and, or, this, the, etc.  You could just jack them off pages like this: http://www.esldesk.com/vocabulary/pronouns , http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-conjunctions.html

Then you just need to decide how many times a word has to occur (either percentage or numeric), and store those tags in a table that shows the connection between tags and content.

To implement the "as the user is typing" part you just need to use a bit of jQuery's ajax functionality to continually call your script that builds the tag list (ie on keydown).

The other option (better user experience) will incorporate a lot of the same elements, but you'll have to think about a bit more.  Some things I would consider:

- Do you want to restrict to certain tags (perhaps you don't want to allow just anyone to create new tags)?
- How you will deal with synonyms
- If you will support multiple languages
- If you want a preference towards suggesting existing tags (which might be close) over suggesting new ones

Once you've fully defined the logic and user experience you can come back to the search algorithm.  MATCH and AGAINST are good options but you may find that a simple LIKE will do it for you.

Good luck = )

Comment: Thanks for your reply Calvin. I think I didn't explain my issue very well. Please, refer to my answer for the clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tag cloud to be generated as the user is typing it, you can do it in two ways.

- Directly update the tag cloud from the input text
- Send the input text to the backend (in realtime using ajax/comet), which then saves, calculates the word frequency and returns data from which you generate the cloud.

I would go with the former using a jQuery plugin such as - http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/tag-cloud